# Convert MySQL result to XML format using PHP with multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get my XML format be like this:

[image: xml format I want]

but my code now does not loop for the 'order_line' array and will return like this:

[image: false XML format]

below are sample of my code I did:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `grn_order` a");

    foreach($result->result() as $row )
    {
        $result_line = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `grn_order_line` a where a.order_no = '$row->order_no'");
        foreach($result_line->result() as $row_line);
        {
            $line = array(
                'guid' => $row_line->guid,
                'itemcode' => $row_line->itemcode,
            );
        }

        $my_array[] = array(
            'order_no' => $row->order_no,
            'loc_code' => $row->loc_code,
            'trans_code' => $row->trans_code,
            'po_no' => $row->po_no,
            'order_line' => $line
        );
    } $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<orders/>');

    // function callback
    $data = $this->array2XML($xml, $my_array);
    print $xml->asXML();

function array2XML($obj, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_numeric($key))

        $key = 'order';

        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $node = $obj->addChild($key);
            $this->array2XML($node, $value);
        }
        else
        {
            $obj->addChild($key, htmlspecialchars($value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, code, config and data should be supplied as text, not images. Please read [this article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) to understand why - the short version is that images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines. If you can amend your question, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You keep on overwriting the last line in your load loop.  Change it to...

```
$line = [];
foreach($result_line->result() as $row_line);
{
    $line[] = array(
        'guid' => $row_line->guid,
        'itemcode' => $row_line->itemcode,
    );
}
```

So each line is added using `$line[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nigel Ren, its work now but the result still does not meet my demand. The return result will loop like this:
<order_line>
            <order>
                <guid>1</guid>
                <itemcode>009898</itemcode>
            </order>
            <order>
                <guid>1</guid>
                <itemcode>77827728</itemcode>
            </order>
        </order_line>

but i want the format without another <order> in <order_online> child just like the picture i attached. could help on this. thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is your `array2XML()` function is adding the extra order element (`$key = 'order';`).  You would be better off building the XML in your main `foreach` loop rather than building an array and trying to convert it afterwards as you get problems like this.